# Trying to filter all of not type with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, addclass

I have a function that add the class light whenever I click a year

```
$('#options li a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        type = $this.attr('class');

    $links.children('li')
        .removeClass('light')
        .filter('.' + type)
        .addClass('light')
    return false;
});
```

I would like to do the reverse  something like :

```
.filter.not('.' + type)
```

but this does not seem to work

is there a way to tell jquery to select everything that is not of X class

Comment: just use `.not()` rather than filter.  Keep in mind this will also break if you ever need to add multiple classes to `$this`, you may want to rethink your approach.  If it's a logical attribute you may want to use a dataset attribute and `.data()` rather than a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you should be able to simply use jQuery's `not()` function instead of `filter()`.

```
$('#options li a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        type = $this.attr('class');

    $links.children('li')
        .removeClass('light')
        .not('.' + type) // <-- *Modified Line*
        .addClass('light')
    return false;
});
```

If you need any more information, take a look at [this section](http://api.jquery.com/not/) of jQuery's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

with [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) you could do:

```
$links.children('li')
  .removeClass('light').filter(function(){
      return $(this).attr("class") !== type;
  }).addClass('light');
```